# Column validation accept a specific character and numbers only

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, validation

So far I manage to make a validation that makes the column only accept numbers:

=ISNUMBER([Column_Name]+0)

But I want users to be able to type ";" inside as column value so only numbers and semicolon allowed.

Anyone have any idea how I can manage that?

Comment: I don't think you can do this using OOTB column validation. Can you use javascript or .NET?

Comment: @ErinL It does work will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(";";[Column_Name]));ISNUMBER([Column_Name]+0))
```

Basicly `FIND()` will look for characters in the column and `ISNUMBER()` will be determine of FINDS true/false.

- Column will accepts both numbers and ";".

Comment: This will also accept "a;3"

Comment: If there is only one semi-column allowed, do a replace of the semi-colon with an empty string **first** then check for number..for multiple '; you have to nest some replaces.

Comment: @ErinL thats true :(

Comment: @DannyEngelman Sadly it can exist unlimited of semi-column. If you know any good solution I would appreciate an answer to the question :)

Comment: This can be done with javascript, or with third-party tools. If you can use javascript, let me know. I'll help get you started.